# Tokenize string with strtok

Tags: c

```
Example Text: 

bclk = /gsrpkg_te/gsrpkg/gsrdie/xxBCLK
```

I would like to ask question regarding to "strtok".Below is an example code with some doubts I have faced.

```
char *p4;
char *p5;
p4 = strtok (eqvline, "=");
p5 = strtok (NULL, ":");
if ( !strcmp (p4, "bclk") ) {
   strcpy ( sa_de_bclk, p5 );
   printf ( "[vTPSim] ---> bclk = %s.\n", p5);
}
```

From the above example text there is no `":"`(colon) anywhere.For my understanding of `strtok()` when there is no the defined symbol is found NULL will be assigned as result.

However, why in this case even if there is no `":"`, `p5` still have the assignment of `"/gsrpkg_te/gsrpkg/gsrdie/xxBCLK"`.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For my understanding of strtok when there is no the defined symbol is found NULL will be assigned as result

Perhaps you are confusing `strtok()` with `strchr()` or `strstr()`. If none of the separator symbols is found in the remaining part of the string, then `strtok()` returns that remaining part (more precisely, a pointer to its first character). It may be the entire string if no delimiters could be found in it at all. [Docs.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html)

Quote from the docs for haters and deniers:

> If no such byte is found, **the current token extends to the end of the string** pointed to by s1, and ***subsequent*** searches for a token shall return a null pointer.

**Subsequent.** Not immediately the call which couldn't find more delimiters, but **the ones following it.**

Comment: @Armin This precisely answers that.

Comment: according to [This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html)`Upon successful completion, strtok() shall return a pointer to the first byte of a token. Otherwise, if there is no token, strtok() shall return a null pointer.`

Comment: @Dayalrai That doesn't concern the second call but the first one. The right quote is: "If no such byte is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by s1, and **subsequent** searches for a token shall return a null pointer" - so not the call that doesn't find the delimiter, but the ones **following it** return `NULL`.

Comment: @H2CO3
Thanks for the info.Now I understand. :)

Comment: @Milk You are welcome. Don't listen to those who say I'm wrong :)

Comment: @H2CO3 *Don't listen to those who say I'm wrong* hahaha ..... I answered in a hurry , just forgot that I should not bring the outside noise here ..... understood what the problem was ..... +1 for you :)

Comment: @PHIfounder Don't worry, it wasn't you :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If first parameter is NULL, then strtok tries to get next token. Since first strtok call was `strtok (eqvline, "=")` with `eqvline != NULL` and token **=** the second call will find the next part which is **/gsrpkg_te/gsrpkg/gsrdie/xxBCLK** in your exmaple.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP knows where the search starts from, he is asking about why the return value of the second call is not `NULL`.

Comment: This is because as I said tokenizing was already started with eqvline != NULL. So strtok(NULL, ":") tries to get next token after "=" even if in second call the token changed. I don't know if this behaviour is standard compliant or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read this documentation of strtok http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/.

> char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
>
> A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.
>
> On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning.

When I look at you example, I would expect that p4 contains "bclk " not "bclk" as you didn't define the whitespace as delimiter. According to the doc, what you did on line 4 (p5 = ...) doesn't have a defined result as you changed delimiters between calls to strtok. I would expect it to use the first delimiters and therefore returning the rest of the string after "=". What it does...

Hope this helps